# Can you shelve code in TFS visual studio, roll back to a previous check in and the shelved code still be there?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, tfvc, shelving

Developers have redesigned the homepage for a website and I amended my automated tests to reflect this and checked in these changes.  The homepage was reverted back to its original layout since the golive date has been pushed back three weeks. I have loaded the automated tests checked in before redesigned homepage changes.  Between now and the new go-live date there will be new functionality added to other pages on the website.  Am I able to

1. Shelve the new code that tests new functionality
2. When the  new homepage is switched on, roll back to the last check in ( the one that had the tests that reflect the new homepage)
3. Unshelve the new code and integrate it with tests for the new homepage

Comment: Visual Studio isn't a source control program, it's an IDE. it uses third party apps like Git for source control, and yes, they can shelve..

Comment: I assume you're using TFS - and yes, that will do what you want.

Comment: It sounds like your process around source control is broken. The redesigned homepage should be developed in a branch. Any tests for the redesigned homepage should be **in the same branch**. There's no need to shelve anything if you're using branches correctly.